# Why is there no "Tabs" Component for the App Page Flexi-Page

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, flexipages, lightning-app-builder

I'm currently trying to enhance one of our managed flexi-pages by adding a "Tabs" component that contains multiple, informative reports that a manager can flick through without taking up the entire screen. The flexi-page I'm trying to edit is an App Page that seems to have significantly fewer component options than the Home/ Record flexi-page types.

***Why doesn't Salesforce include the "Tabs" component for the App Page?***

It seems like a missed opportunity as the Tabs component on the App Page would be a great place to present summary information, or am I just missing a trick here?

[image: Home Page with Tabs Component]
[image: App Page without Tabs Component and many others]